# The ResolveComReference task could not be instantiated from Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm using MsBuild 15.0 APIs to build our own projects.
Because of this version of MsBuild doesn't exist in GAC, I had to use library which is called MSBuildLocator to load assemblies of MsBuild.
When I want to build projects with COMReferences I get below error:

> The "ResolveComReference" task could not be instantiated from
>   "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) The
>   "ResolveComReference" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or
>   failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and
>   the assembly name.

and this is my assembly binding logs

Microsoft.Build.dll

> LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Users\tfsbuild\Desktop\MSBuildTester\MSBuildTester\bin\Debug\MSBuildTester.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.0.0
>   redirected to 15.1.0.0. LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Build,
>   Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tfsbuild/Desktop/MSBuildTester/MSBuildTester/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Build.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tfsbuild/Desktop/MSBuildTester/MSBuildTester/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Build/Microsoft.Build.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tfsbuild/Desktop/MSBuildTester/MSBuildTester/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Build.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tfsbuild/Desktop/MSBuildTester/MSBuildTester/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Build/Microsoft.Build.EXE.
>   LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll

> LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context. WRN: Native image will
>   not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in
>   default load context, like with Assembly.Load(). LOG: Using
>   application configuration file:
>   C:\Users\tfsbuild\Desktop\MSBuildTester\MSBuildTester\bin\Debug\MSBuildTester.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 15.1.0.0
>   redirected to 15.1.0.0. LOG: Post-policy reference:
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tfsbuild/Desktop/MSBuildTester/MSBuildTester/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tfsbuild/Desktop/MSBuildTester/MSBuildTester/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tfsbuild/Desktop/MSBuildTester/MSBuildTester/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/tfsbuild/Desktop/MSBuildTester/MSBuildTester/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2017/Enterprise/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.DLL.
>   LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll
>   LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is:
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a LOG: Where-ref bind Codebase does not
>   match what is found in default context. Keep the result in LoadFrom
>   context. LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll.
>   LOG: Assembly is loaded in LoadFrom load context.

How can I resolve that ?!!

Answer (score 1):

I just got this in the latest build of VS 2019. All I had done since it complied successfully the other day was to add a few lines of trivial code - no new functions. I switched from Debug mode to release and built the solution - no change. I switched back to Debug and the problem went away! NO coding changes.

Then when I went to actually debug the project, the error came back!

It subsequently turned out that Visual Studio was confused. I uninstalled and re-installed it and the problem went away.